# Inserir dados complementares no Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragment

Estou desenvolvendo um app que é composto por 3 Fragments de cadastro, aqui dado o exemplo de A, B, C, sendo que B e C é dependente do A.

Qual é a melhor forma de inserir os dados preenchidos no B e C nos mesmo Child do Fragment A dentro do Firebase.

Utilizei no Fragment A:

```
.child("Profissional").child(idUsuario).child("A").push().setValue(this);
```

e nos B e C:

```
firebase.child("Profissional").child(idUsuario).child("A");
```

Porem ao salvar perdi os dados Salvo do Fragment A.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual a estrutura do firebase?

Comment: Inseri a imagem junto a pergunta. Como não consegui relacionar o Child(Evolucao) e (Prontuario) ao Paciente. Tentei salvar direto os dados no Child(Paciente), mas os dados são sobre posto.

Comment: No caso do B e C, ao invés de utilizar o `setValue`, utilize o `updateChildren`